# Сделать список ссылок из TextView в адаптере

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, adapter

Доброго времени суток.
Такой вопрос, пишу справочник, и создал свой Adapter.
[image: созданный адаптер]
В нем есть textView(URL) который я заполняю ссылками для открытия в браузере, но если просто вставлять ссылки, то получается не красиво. Добавил чтоб было под одним названием, но тогда ссылка не работает, хоть и светиться красным.
[image: код для textview] [image: разметка textView]
Подскажите как исправить эту проблему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<TextView
    android:text="My web site: www.stackoverflow.com"
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web">
</TextView>
```

И в `java` коде:

```
final TextView myClickableUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myClickableUrlTextView);
myClickableUrl.setText("Click my web site: www.stackoverflow.com");
Linkify.addLinks(myClickableUrl, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: K сожалению не получилось.